# Run command from celery

Tags: celery

First I have a module which I run using celery.

Second I have another module which I run to push a task to the celery worker. It imports the first module and calls it async.

Now the first module loads some large files which only need to be loaded once. I wish to load then when celery starts, however when I run the 2nd module to push the task to the celery worked I do NOT wish to import these files again.

Can I call a function with celery so that it loads first time when the workers are initialised and then not call this function again when I run the 2nd module which just pushes the task to the worker?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make this happen is to pass the module to your celery workers, rather than have them import it, on its own right.

For example, something like this

import big_module

tasks = [ foo.s(big_module), foo.s(big_module) ... ]

now, inside of foo, rather than importing the module, just access it like any other object.

Answer (score 1):

Each worker instantiates the task as a singleton, so you can cache anything you want in the task object.

It sounds like you want to share between different tasks. In that case, you can create a singleton of your own. It will be loaded once per worker. If you want multiple workers to share it you'll need a cache (memcache, redis, django db, an optimized file, ?).